# Users can set cookies in console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm wondering the best way to implement cookies to my site. I would like a user to be able to edit a given post based off a cookie that I set at the time the post is created.

I'm using Angular to set the cookie. ie:

```
var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
$cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
```

(per the Angular tutorial for $cookies).

My question is more at the core of how to use cookies. Wouldn't it be easy for a user to set the cookie using the console? ie:

```
 document.cookie = 'key=value';
```

And get access to a post for editing? Perhaps I should be creating a unique id to use as a cookie that I then check for when the actual creator visits the page? If so, how might I go about this to best ensure only the actual creator of the post has access to editing?

Comment: Are you handle sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict JavaScript manipulation by setting the `HttpOnly` flag in the cookie on a response. The console won't be able to set it programatically.

Comment: How might I set the HttpOnly flag on my cookie?

Comment: @AndrewHansen what are you using on the server side?

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: Yes. It's a MEAN stack app